# int to char type conversion

Tags: c

I have the following snippet of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int i1 = 0x18f;
 char c1 = i1;
 char c2 = 15;
 unsigned short s1 = 0174670;
 printf("1) %o\n", i1);
 printf("2) %d\n", c1);
 i1 = c1;
 printf("3) %d\n", i1 & c2);
 printf("4) %x\n", s1 ^= 0x5555); 
}
```

with this output

```
1) 617
2) -113
3) 15
4) aced
```

Could someone explain why the second and fourth outputs come out to -113 and aced respectively. Thank you.

Comment: I can understand why you are confused about the second. But why about the fourth?

Comment: It's a hexadecimal number. Sounds familiar?

Comment: %x produces hex. ACED basae 16 = 10 * 16^3 + 12 * 16^2 + 14 * 16^1 + 13 * 16^0 (just like 456 base 10 = 4 * 10^2 + 5 * 10^1 + 6 * 10^0)

Comment: This is in hex.

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour, absolutely anything can happen.

Comment: `int i1 = 0x18f; printf("1) %o\n", i1);` is not UB per C11 §6.5.2.2 6 "one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the
corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`char c1 = i1;` is undefined behaviour. `i1` is 399 which needs at least 2 bytes to be represented while char is 1 byte. The output you are having is just the truncation of 399 = 110001111 in binary to 1 byte: 10001111 = signed -133 but since it's UB it could be anything else just as well

The fourth is just the hex representation of the number

Comment: It is actually *implementation-defined*. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3

Comment: "i1 is 399 which needs at least 2 bytes to be represented " - wrong. And you did not catch the true UB.